# R: Creating new dummy variable column based on certain characters

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to use R to add a new dummy variable column to my data frame. The criteria will be based on basketball player positions.

I would still like to keep the position column, just as a reference.

The dummy variable, guard = 1 for "PG" (Point guard) and "SG" (Shooting guard), and = 0 for "SF","PF" and "C"

Additionally, if there are two positions combined (e.g. "SG-SF"), use only the first position (e.g. "SG").

```
df <- data.frame (player = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"),
position = c("PF","SF","PG-SG", "SG-SF", "C", "PF", "SF-PF"))
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your logic, 'SG" is repeated for guard 1 and 0

Comment: `df$guard <- +grepl('PG|SG', df$position)` will do the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the first word and then use `%in%`, then coerce to binary with `as.integer or` +`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
     mutate(guard = +(str_extract(position, "\\w+") %in% c("PG", "SG")))
```

-output

```
#   player position guard
#1      a       PF     0
#2      b       SF     0
#3      c  PG - SG     1
#4      d    SG-SF     1
#5      e        C     0
#6      f       PF     0
#7      g    SF-PF     0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$guard <- +(sub("\\s*-\\s*.*", "", df$position) %in% c("PG", "SG"))
```

Answer (score 0):

another `base R` solution based on `grepl`

```
df[["guard"]] <- +grepl("^PG|SG", df[["position"]])
```

Regex: `grepl` (returns bool for pattern found in string) for 'PG' or 'SG' at the begining `^` of a string in column `position` (`+` turns the `TRUE|FALSE` result into `1|0`)